# Mirror Reflection on a page in TideSDK

Tags: tidesdk

I am trying to port a web application over to TideSDK and so far everything has been great aside from one problem I have found where the page seems be reflecting on itself. What I mean is that over the top of the regular page is basically an extra layer where all of the page elements such as buttons have been flipped.

The page itself has an image slider on it that utilises things such as webkit transforms but I'm not sure if this would create the effect I'm getting.

Has anyone encountered this problem and is there a way or sorting it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same when using TideSDK on Mac so I'm assuming you're also on Mac. The problem is not of TideSDK but of the webkit in OSX version of TideSDK, this webkit is 2yrs old and I remember reading an article that says 2yrs back the safari webkit(same as webkit in TideSDK OSX) doesn't support transforms. So you can't use pseudo classes in your OSX application. Try

```
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
```

On the element/parent-element (which ever works) that you might want some kind of transformation on

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this longer than I want to admit, but the problem went away when I removed the height property from the main html body in the css.

```
body{
    height: 100% /* <-- get rid of this.
    /*Other stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The backface visibility worked for me... I used the following at the top of the main CSS.

```
* {
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

( I didn't have a body{width/height}. )

I still have some mirroring seemingly under the BODY element. While the mirroring is covered by the body (so users don't see it all the time), when I resize the app window, I can see the inverse underneath because there was jitter during resize. (I have a window.resize listener that's pretty intense.)

But at least all the other stuff doesn't mirror now :/